# Can I run my Expo app on multiple iOS Simulators at once?

Tags: ios-simulator, expo

Is it possible to run an [Expo](https://expo.io) app on multiple versions of iOS Simulator at once? It would be really nice to have two or three iPhones refreshing automatically, so that it's easy to tests the layout with different screen sizes.

(I know I can do this with multiple hardware devices, and I know that I can change was device iOS Simulator should use.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This command:

```
expo-cli ios
```

does not let you choose the actual simulator on which it should run.

Assuming the Expo viewer app is installed and default ports are used, this command allows you to open it on a specific simulator:

```
xcrun simctl openurl <some-device-id> exp://127.0.0.1:19000
```

**Run Expo on Multiple Simulators**

It can be run on multiple simulators at once.

Since it's a bit cumbersome to restart the selected simulators from scratch every day, here's a small shell script that automatically starts three specific simulators based on their device IDs and opens the Expo application on them:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a simulators=("0FAE2F92-9EF7-4C4A-8F9D-097A056F8CC0" "BFCDD662-E4DE-4C08-9DF6-CAACA7C00CEC" "1A6959A0-C10F-474B-96C5-7E8955FBDD80")

for i in "${simulators[@]}"
do
    xcrun instruments -w $i
    #xcrun simctl install $i ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.14.0.app
    xcrun simctl openurl $i exp://127.0.0.1:19000      
done
```

Here you can see three different simulator device IDs in an array. Of course you have to use your own device IDs of the simulators you want to use.

BTW: if you once installed the Exponent-x.x.x.app it is available in a hidden folder in your home directory. So by calling:

```
xcrun simctl install <some-device-id> ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.14.0.app
```

you can even install the Expo app in a specific simulator (see also the commented line in the shell script above) from the command line.

**NOTE: The `Exponent-2.14.0.app` version will change as the Expo SDK is upgraded. `Exponent-2.14.0.app` comes with `expo-cli --version` 3.13.1, which is current as of February 22, 2020.**

**How to Determine the Simulator IDs**

```
xcrun simctl list
```

This displays the corresponding device ID for each simulator.

A small note: Over time, there are several simulator entries that are no longer available after an upgrade. To remove them with a simple command, proceed as follows:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```

**Demo**

Here is a short demo of the script:

- three simulators are started
- the Expo app is opened

The source code of the demo app is then changed. All three simulators are updated at once.

[image: demo of multiple iOS simulators]

Comment: What a wonderfully thorough answer, Stephan.  I hope it reaches more people than just me.

Comment: This is really an interesting way to handle the simulators. Thanks for the script too!

Comment: Wonderful answer @stephen. I've edited the answer to update the expo app version. Is there a way to use a glob or some matching pattern so that will just work in the future? Expo.*\.app would be a rough guess at what would work. Thoughts? Sorry, bash n00b here.

Comment: shortcut: if you pass in the wrong device IDs (ie the ones in the script above) , mac will tell you it couldn't find them, but then it lists all of the available simulators and IDs so you can just copy them from the terminal instead of having to go into xcode and find them.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer does not work in 2021 as "instruments" is not available in Xcode 13 anymore.

Please follow the instruction below:

Replace the device IDs with your device IDs `xcrun simctl list`. Also, replace the Expo version with what you have on your machine.

```
#!/bin/zsh
declare -a simulators=("27D6B718-8348-4C4D-ADFC-6506C2A88EED" "531A59B8-6197-4620-904B-E55308D1EE96" "C08532FE-3CE4-4BB7-A04C-795F2FA7EFE1")
echo "STARTED"
open -a Simulator
wait_time=1
for i in $simulators[@]
do
    echo "Boot $i"
    xcrun simctl boot $i
    sleep $wait_time
    echo "Install Expo $i"
    xcrun simctl install $i ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.19.6.tar.app
    sleep $wait_time
    echo "Lauch Expo $i"
    xcrun simctl openurl $i exp://127.0.0.1:19000
    sleep $wait_time
done
echo "FINISHED"
```

Comment: Worked in my case, thanks a lot!

Comment: @H.Qasemi Glad, it worked!

Comment: How do you know the correct Exponent ~ [version] ?

Comment: @HadrienJaubert Usually, it's under ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/ path. The version could be found in the file name like Exponent-{version}.tar.app. Example: Exponent-2.19.6.tar.app and the version is 2.19.6 in this case. If you are asking about finding the right version, then my suggestion would be to go with the latest you have in this path or update/download the latest.